# Store Username and Password with a pre-configured Connection

Tags: windows, batch-file

I managed to create an executable to run `Store Username and Password` with this code:

```
rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr
exit
```

I'm asking if it's possible to prompt the windows to configure the new connection with the address already configured. As you can see in the image below, I would like to let the user that open this file just fill out his user and password.

[image: WindowsCredential]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use CMDKEY.exe
http://ss64.com/nt/cmdkey.html

EDIT:

```
@echo off

:username
cls
SET "username="
SET /P "username=Enter your username:"
IF NOT DEFINED username GOTO username

:password
cls
SET "password="
SET /P "password=Enter your password:"
IF NOT DEFINED password GOTO password

cmdkey /add:Server /user:%username% /pass:%password%

pause
```

Second EDIT: Code with Hidden Password Input

```
@echo off &setlocal

:username
cls
SET "username="
SET /P "username=Enter your username:"
IF NOT DEFINED username GOTO username

:password
cls
<nul set /p "=Enter your password: "
call :HInput password
IF NOT DEFINED password GOTO password

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cmdkey /add:Server /user:%username% /pass:!password!
pause
goto :eof


:HInput [ByRef_VarName]
:: inspired by Carlos
:: improved by pieh-ejdsch
if "%__HI__%" neq "__HI__" (
  setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
  set "S=" &set "N=0" &set "__HI__=__HI__"
  for /f %%i in ('"prompt;$h&for %%i in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%i"
)
set "C="
for /f "eol=1 delims=" %%i in ('xcopy /lwq "%~f0" :\') do set "C=%%i"
set "C=%C:~-1%"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if not defined C (
  echo(
  if "%~1"=="" (
    echo(!S!
    endlocal &endlocal &exit /b %N%
  ) else (
    if defined S (
      for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%i in ("!S!") do endlocal &endlocal &set "%~1=%%i" &exit /b %N%
    ) else endlocal &endlocal &set "%~1=" &exit /b 0
  )
)
if "!BS!"=="!C!" (
  set "C="
  if defined S set /a "N -= 1" &set "S=!S:~,-1!" &<nul set /p "=%BS% %BS%"
) else set /a "N += 1" &<nul set /p "=*"
if not defined S (
  endlocal &set "N=%N%" &set "S=%C%"
) else for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%i in ("!S!") do endlocal &set "N=%N%" &set "S=%%i%C%"
goto HInput
```

Comment: Because I need to pre-set the username. I need a script just to pre-set the connection and then let the user fill his name and password.

Comment: @gmeroni use the SET /P command to ask for the username and password in a batch file.

Comment: I'm new to this, so can you be more specific? If i type `cmdkey /add:myconnection /set /P` the CMD say "Reading Smart card-Access Denied"

Comment: @gmeroni, see my edit. If you plan on writing more batch files in the future, here is a site that lists all the commands you can use.  http://ss64.com/nt/  Has examples for how to use all the commands.

Comment: Thanks, one more thing. I saw that is possibile to hide password...but SET command doesn't have this option and i can't managed to use read function....any ideas?

Comment: @gmeroni that code should thoroughly confuse you.  But it works.